# How route in symfony by first two segemts link with any segments

Tags: symfony, routes

Hi i am trying find solution for annotation routing in symfony 3. It is for link on images witch are on another server (temporary solution).

links can be:

> /images/photos/1/1.jpg

or

> /images/photos/5/7/98/52/45.jpg

so any segments.

so all links start with /images/photos/ but after that they can has any other segments as path to file.

I was trying:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/images/photos/{requestAddress}", name="front.imageredirect.action")
 */
```

But without success. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to do this with annotation routing

But it is possible with yaml configuration

```
catch_them_all_route:
    path: '/images/photos/{catchall}'
    defaults:
        _controller: 'AppBundle:YourController:catch'
    requirements:
        catchall: ".+"
```

catchAction will catch all calls to an url starting with `/images/photos/`

```
public function catchAction(Request $request) { 
    $segments = [];
    if($subPath = $request->attributes->get('catchall')) {
        $segments = explode('/', $subPath);
    }
    return $this->json($segments);
}
```

From here segments will contains all parts after `/images/photos`

Example with a call to `/images/photos/5/7/98/52/45.jpg`

`$segments` will be

- 5
- 7
- 98
- 52
- 45.jpg

I didn't tested it, let me know if something is wrong :)

Comment: Yep it works thx but one notice in controller method can be: catchAction($catchall) {}. But i am not sure about security...

Comment: `$request->attributes->get('catchall')` and `catchAction($catchall)` is the same. What is your security concern ?